# Ubuntu 20.04 with root on ZFS errors after 'apt dist-upgrade'

Tags: 20.04, zfs

I've been running 20.04 w/ root on ZFS for a couple of months now, with no major problems.

This morning, I ran an `apt dist-upgrade`, and I got the following errors:

```
mjb@feynmann:~$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up zfsutils-linux (0.8.3-1ubuntu12.1) ...
zfs-import-scan.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
zfs-import-scan.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Job for zfs-mount.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process.
See "systemctl status zfs-mount.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript zfs-mount, action "start" failed.
● zfs-mount.service - Mount ZFS filesystems
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/zfs-mount.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: signal) since Wed 2020-06-03 09:38:01 EDT; 4ms ago
       Docs: man:zfs(8)
    Process: 760032 ExecStart=/sbin/zfs mount -a (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
   Main PID: 760032 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)

Jun 03 09:38:00 feynmann systemd[1]: Starting Mount ZFS filesystems...
Jun 03 09:38:00 feynmann zfs[760032]: cannot mount '/root': directory is not empty
Jun 03 09:38:00 feynmann zfs[760032]: cannot mount '/var/cache': directory is not empty
Jun 03 09:38:00 feynmann zfs[760032]: cannot mount '/var/lib/AccountsService': directory is not empty
Jun 03 09:38:00 feynmann zfs[760032]: free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Jun 03 09:38:01 feynmann systemd[1]: zfs-mount.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
Jun 03 09:38:01 feynmann systemd[1]: zfs-mount.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Jun 03 09:38:01 feynmann systemd[1]: Failed to start Mount ZFS filesystems.
dpkg: error processing package zfsutils-linux (--configure):
 installed zfsutils-linux package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of zfs-initramfs:
 zfs-initramfs depends on zfsutils-linux (>= 0.8.3-1ubuntu12.1); however:
  Package zfsutils-linux is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package zfs-initramfs (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of zfs-zed:
 zfs-zed depends on zfsutils-linux (>= 0.8.3-1ubuntu12.1); however:
  Package zfsutils-linux is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package zfs-zed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message i
ndicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                      Errors were encountered while processing:
 zfsutils-linux
 zfs-initramfs
 zfs-zed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

More info:

```
mjb@feynmann:~$ sudo systemctl status zfs-mount.service
● zfs-mount.service - Mount ZFS filesystems
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/zfs-mount.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: signal) since Wed 2020-06-03 09:38:01 EDT; 1min 9s ago
       Docs: man:zfs(8)
    Process: 760032 ExecStart=/sbin/zfs mount -a (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
   Main PID: 760032 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)

Jun 03 09:38:00 feynmann systemd[1]: Starting Mount ZFS filesystems...
Jun 03 09:38:00 feynmann zfs[760032]: cannot mount '/root': directory is not empty
Jun 03 09:38:00 feynmann zfs[760032]: cannot mount '/var/cache': directory is not empty
Jun 03 09:38:00 feynmann zfs[760032]: cannot mount '/var/lib/AccountsService': directory is not empty
Jun 03 09:38:00 feynmann zfs[760032]: free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Jun 03 09:38:01 feynmann systemd[1]: zfs-mount.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
Jun 03 09:38:01 feynmann systemd[1]: zfs-mount.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Jun 03 09:38:01 feynmann systemd[1]: Failed to start Mount ZFS filesystems.
mjb@feynmann:~$ sudo journalctl -xe
-- The process' exit code is 'killed' and its exit status is 6.
Jun 03 09:38:01 feynmann systemd[1]: zfs-mount.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit zfs-mount.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'signal'.
Jun 03 09:38:01 feynmann systemd[1]: Failed to start Mount ZFS filesystems.
-- Subject: A start job for unit zfs-mount.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit zfs-mount.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 16641 and the job result is failed.
Jun 03 09:38:01 feynmann dbus-daemon[2075]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.PackageKit' unit='packagekit.service' requested by>
Jun 03 09:38:01 feynmann systemd[1]: Starting PackageKit Daemon...
-- Subject: A start job for unit packagekit.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit packagekit.service has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 16649.
Jun 03 09:38:01 feynmann PackageKit[760066]: daemon start
Jun 03 09:38:01 feynmann dbus-daemon[2075]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit'
Jun 03 09:38:01 feynmann systemd[1]: Started PackageKit Daemon.
-- Subject: A start job for unit packagekit.service has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit packagekit.service has finished successfully.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 16649.
Jun 03 09:38:01 feynmann sudo[759659]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jun 03 09:39:10 feynmann sudo[760629]:      mjb : TTY=pts/4 ; PWD=/home/mjb ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl status zfs-mount.service
Jun 03 09:39:10 feynmann sudo[760629]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jun 03 09:39:10 feynmann sudo[760629]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jun 03 09:39:15 feynmann sudo[760671]:      mjb : TTY=pts/4 ; PWD=/home/mjb ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl -xe
Jun 03 09:39:15 feynmann sudo[760671]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

Even more info:

It appears that the problem is with `apt install zfsuitls-linux`, which gets:

```
mjb@feynmann:~$ sudo apt install zfsutils-linux
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
zfsutils-linux is already the newest version (0.8.3-1ubuntu12.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up zfsutils-linux (0.8.3-1ubuntu12.1) ...
zfs-import-scan.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
zfs-import-scan.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Job for zfs-mount.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process.
See "systemctl status zfs-mount.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript zfs-mount, action "start" failed.
● zfs-mount.service - Mount ZFS filesystems
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/zfs-mount.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: signal) since Thu 2020-06-04 05:49:45 EDT; 4ms ago
       Docs: man:zfs(8)
    Process: 1176564 ExecStart=/sbin/zfs mount -a (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
   Main PID: 1176564 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)

Jun 04 05:49:45 feynmann systemd[1]: Starting Mount ZFS filesystems...
Jun 04 05:49:45 feynmann zfs[1176564]: cannot mount '/root': directory is not empty
Jun 04 05:49:45 feynmann zfs[1176564]: cannot mount '/var/cache': directory is not empty
Jun 04 05:49:45 feynmann zfs[1176564]: cannot mount '/var/lib/AccountsService': directory is not empty
Jun 04 05:49:45 feynmann zfs[1176564]: free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Jun 04 05:49:45 feynmann systemd[1]: zfs-mount.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
Jun 04 05:49:45 feynmann systemd[1]: zfs-mount.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Jun 04 05:49:45 feynmann systemd[1]: Failed to start Mount ZFS filesystems.
dpkg: error processing package zfsutils-linux (--configure):
 installed zfsutils-linux package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                      dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of zfs-initramfs:
 zfs-initramfs depends on zfsutils-linux (>= 0.8.3-1ubuntu12.1); however:
  Package zfsutils-linux is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package zfs-initramfs (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of zfs-zed:
 zfs-zed depends on zfsutils-linux (>= 0.8.3-1ubuntu12.1); however:
  Package zfsutils-linux is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package zfs-zed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 zfsutils-linux
 zfs-initramfs
 zfs-zed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Upon closer examination, I see:

```
Job for zfs-mount.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process.
    See "systemctl status zfs-mount.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

So, I tried:

```
mjb@feynmann:~$ systemctl status zfs-mount.service
● zfs-mount.service - Mount ZFS filesystems
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/zfs-mount.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: signal) since Thu 2020-06-04 05:49:45 EDT; 3min 1s ago
       Docs: man:zfs(8)
    Process: 1176564 ExecStart=/sbin/zfs mount -a (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
   Main PID: 1176564 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
```

And finally:

```
mjb@feynmann:~$ sudo /sbin/zfs mount -a
cannot mount '/root': directory is not empty
cannot mount '/var/cache': directory is not empty
cannot mount '/var/lib/AccountsService': directory is not empty
Segmentation fault
```

At which point, I'm lost.

Still more info:

```
mjb@feynmann:~$ cat /etc/fstab 
# UNCONFIGURED FSTAB FOR BASE SYSTEM
PARTUUID=84ba431b-1974-486b-b859-41f7417c5b1e /boot/efi vfat nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=1 0 1
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu /boot zfs nodev,relatime,x-systemd.requires=zfs-import-bpool.service 0 0
rpool/var/log /var/log zfs nodev,relatime 0 0
rpool/var/spool /var/spool zfs nodev,relatime 0 0
rpool/var/tmp /var/tmp zfs nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/zvol/rpool/swap none swap discard 0 0
```

Why would my fstab be unconfigured?

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I still don't have the root cause, but, when I installed this system, a day or two after 20.04 was released, I just used the 18.04 Root On ZFS directions, and it seemed to work fine, for the most part.

But, since the official directions for 20.04 Root on ZFS are out now, I did a complete wipe and reload of my laptop, with the new directions (which do vary on a fw points).

So far, so good.  No problems, everything is running fine.

I would have felt more satisfied if I found the root cause and solution to my problem, but a wipe and reload does seem to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having an issue like this try moving the directory out of the way like `mv /var/cache /var/cache.bak` and the remount the directory with `zfs rpool/var/cache`. Once all the ZFS mounts have been properly mounted, the update with `apt upgrade` should work.

If you are missing any data then it will be in your `.bak` directories.

My guess is, Ubuntu maybe creates directories during the distribution update process which clash with the directories ZFS  wants to mount.