# booting to emergency mode after 20.04.5 (focal) to 22.04 (jammy) upgrade

Tags: boot, upgrade, zfs

Back in 2020, I installed 20.04 using the openZFS on root option provided in the Ubuntu installer. Now (Oct 2022) I ran:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

and it completed and rebooted but GRUB menu still shows 20.04 and ends up in emergency mode. Clearly something failed. Please help me find out why/how the upgrade broke the system and how I can fix it!

Screenshots:

- [emergency mode](https://ibb.co/tbHzWns)
- [old snapshot options I could revert to](https://ibb.co/LZ7219z)
- [zfs modules seem to be loading..](https://ibb.co/F06zbXK)
- [but then this happens](https://ibb.co/dcTmnNp)
- [and this](https://ibb.co/R7FnZpm)
- [some of the journalctl -xb output](https://ibb.co/hHMHpZN)
- [more](https://ibb.co/w4QX0XH)

I can get more if there is something I should look for in particular that would help you help me.

Also, as a last resort, I was thinking I could revert to a pre-upgrade snapshot but it looks like they are all 2+ years old. So the automatic snapshots stopped working silently at some point.

This is on a Thinkpad T410 with BIOS boot (not UEFI).

Can I adapt one of these instructions to my scenario?:
[reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/zfs/comments/oy6d5h/comment/h7r3kj5/?context=3)
[askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225751/recovering-a-borked-grub-with-a-ubuntu-19-10-zfs-root-filesystem)
[tecmint](https://www.tecmint.com/rescue-repair-and-reinstall-grub-boot-loader-in-ubuntu/)

This is the current disk/partition layout:

sda   disk 931.5G Samsung SSD 860 QVO 1TB (just under half full)
sda1  part   512M                         vfat        (ESP pri part)
sda2  part     1K                                     (extended)
sda5  part     2G                         zfs_member  (bpool)
sda6  part   927G                         zfs_member  (rpool)

[This is the output from running the boot-repair tool:](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7KdpyWxg53/) (it seems to suggest changing bios to UEFI boot mode which I am trying now.

This Ask Ubuntu Question could be the same issue: (no solution!)

- [Ubuntu 20.04 with root on ZFS errors after 'apt dist-upgrade'](https://askubuntu.com/q/1246502/57576)

[This problem seems common:](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/utmx1p/cant_upgrade_to_2204_existing_ubuntu_2004_zfs_on/)